# Area 51 site proposal: StackExchange API Application Development

Tags: discussion

The question was closed instead of migrated so I have opened a new question on meta

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/55163

---

Currently intended role of StackApps.com is not entirely clear.

Right now, it seems to be focused on shaking out the bugs in the API and providing a somewhat noisy area of app announcement, via the 'apps' tab, that to a non-technical user just looking for a cool app is likely to be intimidating to the point of being unusable.

If the 'apps' tab is intended to ultimately be an end-user resource for finding apps, it will have to be redesigned to be more app-store-ish and controlled by more than adding a tag.

But what I do not see a lot of is 'how can i do xxxx with the api' and 'how to do xxxx' with the api, basically an api app developer centric site with code snippet heavy content similar to Stack Overflow..

here is the Area 51 proposal for such an api app developer site:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10133/stackexchange-api-development?referrer=muNxqcUO5cppdZnri3IIJQ2

Comment: This is about the *site* StackApps, and not really about the API itself.  Belongs on meta.

Comment: There is no way currently to migrate questions to Meta.

Comment: @geo & kevin. ok, then the workflow is complete.

Comment: I'm currently working on a site you can all come and list your apps on - kind of like an app store. It will have: OpenID support, integrated bug tracking, and more... Stay tuned!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/936/stacklist-list-your-apps-track-bugs-and-more) out.