# StackList - List Your Apps, Track Bugs, and More!

Tags: app, website

## StackList

http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/

---

**Update:** There are already [quite a few apps](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/applications.php) and [libraries](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/libraries.php) listed and the number is growing by the day. Don't put off listing yours!

---

StackList is a website that aims to fill the gap left by StackApps (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/55163/area-51-site-proposal-stackexchange-api-application-development)) when it comes to listing your applications, tracking bugs, dealing with user support, etc.

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stacklist.png

StackList enables you to browse the applications listed on the site, vote on them, and submit your own applications. StackList uses OpenID for authentication.

Some of the existing features:

- Keep track of bugs
- Integration with other StackExchange sites
- Screenshots for applications
- Search for apps by name, etc.
- Tag management, searching, etc.

Some of the planned features:

- Accept some HTML in text entries.
- Notification system
- Feature requests

I strongly encourage everyone with an application here on StackApps to join StackList and list the application there.

---

- **July 23** - Added RSS feeds to the site.
- **July 16** - Completed the initial part of the API. Details [here](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/api/).
- **July 11** - Created a page to view apps with a certain tag.
- **July 6** - Fixed bug where long links would mess up page layout.
- **July 3** - Finished bug reports page. Added persistent logins. Added search bar. Links are now recognized and 'HTML-ified'
- **July 2** - Finished user profile pages including integration with SE sites. Removed ability to vote for one's own apps and removed such votes. App's rating shows total votes now. Completed 90% of 'bug management' code.
- **July 1** - Added ability to edit apps that have been added. Added logo / screenshot to apps. Partially added user profile page.
- **June 30** - Added library link beside logo. Added tags to apps.
- **June 29** - Launched site. Fixed OpenID bug.

---

*Any feedback / comments / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: I like the idea, george. And the site looks smooth. I am a bit unsure of the implications of competing with the sure to be forthcoming so app store. b.t.w. your oid is not accepting my google oid.

Comment: @code: *[Sigh]* - now I know why OpenID doesn't enjoy widespread use :) This will be looked into soon. As far as the SO app store... how do you know they are making one...?

Comment: how could they not be? so is like the borg. in any case, get your oid issues cleared up and i will add a few goodies.

Comment: @code: Okay. In order to debug this, I'm going to need to ask you to try signing in [here](http://openid.quickmediasolutions.com). Then please copy the output to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or something. (Or email it to me: `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`)

Comment: no need for pastebin. the redirect to google just says 'The page you requested is invalid.'

Comment: @code: Hmmm... you got me stumped. I updated my PHP OpenID library just in case... Is there any chance the endpoint you're using is malfunctioning in some way? Would it be possible to see a screenshot?

Comment: @code: After some Googling and such I **think** I might have fixed it. Please try it again and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @code: Are you going to submit some goodies? :)

Comment: well, your test page accepts my oid, but stacklist does not.

Comment: @code: Are you sure? I just tried putting `'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'` into the box and it takes me to the login page. Are you getting the same error as you were before?

Comment: Getting to the login page is no problem. The return trip is the problem. `An error occurred during the sign-in process. Please try again`

Comment: @code: Argh! Those are the hardest to debug. Okay, please try logging in again - this time it will give me a huge dump when there's an error which I can examine. Thanks!

Comment: ok. you should have a full error log now.

Comment: @code: **Thanks for all your help!** I *finally* think I found the bug now. Thanks for the patience. You should have no problems now :)

Comment: sho nuff. needs edit link for app owner.

Comment: @code: I know. It's on my list :) What do you think? What are your impressions?

Comment: i still think there may be some issues going forward, but as I said, it is a good idea and the site looks smooth. keep it simple. but when you get a chance, figure out how to smoothly add os/platform field so peeps can not be bothered with 10,000 linux apps written by george edison when they are looking for windows apps. so +1 is my impression. don't spend it all in one place.

Comment: @code: Ya, I'm going to add tags for that sort of thing... like platform, etc.

Comment: Can we have a place to list libraries too?

Comment: @jjnguy: In the works!

Comment: @code: I posted a comment to you on my site :)

Comment: @jjnguy: ...and **completed!** You can now list your libraries / wrappers now. When you list your creation, just make sure `'library'` is checked.

Comment: @jjnguy: You're welcome! And it looks like it is the top rated item on there so far. Eventually, I'm going to make a separate tab for the libraries so that they are separate from the apps. Any suggestions for features / improvements?

Comment: @George...I rated it 5 stars.  You may wanna make it so that the person who submitted the app/library can't vote for it.

Comment: @jjnguy: ...and **completed!** There is now a new link beside the logo for libraries. (And your library is the only one!) And yes, you can vote for your own *at least for now*. There is future consideration to remove this ability.

Comment: @code: ...and **completed!** You can now edit your listings *and* you can add a screenshot / logo to it!

Comment: you might want to give some context to the star ratings by showing the vote count.

Comment: @code: ...and **completed!** Votes for user's own products have been removed and you can now see the total number of votes for each item. **And** I finished the user profile page. (You might want to change yours.)

Comment: @jjnguy: I fixed the voting system: all votes for user's own products have been removed and will not be allowed in the future. Also, you can see the total votes for an item now.

Comment: @George Edison: I'm probably missing something, but how do I get to my user page (in order to edit it)? The only way I've found is to go to the general users page and click on my user. I'd expect to be able to click on my name, Stack-style :)

Comment: @Edan: You should just be able to click on your name on any of the pages... try [this](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/view_profile.php?id=14) page. There should be a button under your pictures saying "Edit my profile". You can then click on that.

Comment: Also another few minor things. The username field appears to be a display name, not an actual user name. I recommend calling it that to prevent confusion (I originally used edanm since that's my "default" for username fields). Also, I notice the username you write at the top of the page doesn't change when I change my username (it does change on the front page).

Comment: @George: Yeah I know how to actually edit, I'm talking about getting to my user page in the first place. When this site will have many users, I won't always be able to quickly find a post with my name on it on the front page, so I'd like to be able to click my name at the top-right corner to get to my userpage, like in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Edan: Oh, okay. I'll fix that. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Edan: I changed the 'username' field to 'display name'. Also, any changes to your username will now be reflected on the top of the page. I'm also working on a search capability. (Both for apps and users.)

Comment: Great site! I listed New Q! on it. One thing I'd like to see added is auto-complete for tags so it's easier to choose tags that have already been used like on SO. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam: Yes, expect to see this feature added soon. More than one person has requested it.

Comment: @sys: That's a standard message that gets displayed each time you vote.

Comment: @George ok forget it.

Comment: There's one application StackList doesn't have listed that it should, and that's StackList! I was looking it up so I could suggest you add some RSS feeds to the site.

Comment: @Evan: Feel free to post comments for StackList here.

Comment: @George I would change the main template overthere; your app looks good in term of features but, imho, it is not that appealing with that template. Don't take it personal, just a suggestion ;).

Comment: Can I suggest StackList would really benefit from some RSS feeds. One for new apps, and one for new libraries (and perhaps one combined) at least. Thanx.

Comment: @Evan: I'll try to add that soon.

Comment: @Evan: ...and **done!** I added an RSS feed for each of the items you suggested.