# Using meta.stackoverflow.com as a support channel for a stackapp?

Tags: support

Is it okay to recommend using meta.stackoverflow.com as a support channel for stackapp I've written.  For example, say I had been the person who wrote [StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/), on the bottom of the home page could I have something like:

> If you have any questions about StackPrinter, please post them on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) **with the tag "stackprinter"** for the quickest response. Otherwise you can [email me](http://my.email.address@stackprinter.com)

Would this be considered acceptable, or an abuse? Perhaps we need a support.stackapps.com stack-exchange site?

Comment: +1 You are the person who wrote StackPrinter? Really? Good job man :)! Your awesome app really deserve a big prizee.

Comment: Nope, wasn't me. I was just using it as an example. That's why I phrased it above as "say I _had_ been the person who wrote..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No.** See [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1185/using-meta-stackoverflow-com-as-a-support-channel-for-a-stackapp/1188#1188) for the official response from SO staff, which is fair enough.

**However** George made the [good suggestion](https://stackapps.com/questions/1185/using-meta-stackoverflow-com-as-a-support-channel-for-a-stackapp/1189#1189) that we use [StackList](https://stackapps.com/questions/936/stacklist-list-your-apps-track-bugs-and-more) that he developed for this. It is an integrated comments/reviews/bug reporting system for StackExchange related applications, so looks perfect for the task. Thanks George!

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

[app]s are not owned, or operated by Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.

meta.stackoverflow is for support, discussion, etc. focused on stackoverflow.com and the StackExchange family of sites.

*Not for support of third-party products, like [app]s*

Providing a means of reporting problems using an [app] is the responsibility of the [app] developer.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Good to have an official answer to the question on record.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>that was before stackapps.com existed. This is the place do discuss all things related to the API.</strike>

I guess I misread the question.

This is my take on it:

Users should not be coming to stackapps and posting [app] support questions, but the [app]/[library] announcement post is meant for those sorts of things. e.g. examples, docs, questions (in the form of an answer) comments, feedback etc etc. as we have all been doing with demonstrable benefit.

How many bugs/suggestions do we see simply mentioned in a comment only to have it fixed in short measure and for all to see.

Of course, an app should have an official home, but while we are all learning the in's and outs and announcing new work, this centralized location is a perfect place to communicate within our small cadre of devs for qualified and agile discourse.

On the announcement post of the code in question of course.

That's just my .2 pesos.

Comment: stackapps is not for reporting problems with [app]s, its for announcing [app]s (and keeping those announcements up to date, etc.) and discussion about the API (including usage and future developments).

Answer (score 2):

Uh... I hate to plug my own stuff, but it directly applies.

Why not use [StackList](https://stackapps.com/questions/936/stacklist-list-your-apps-track-bugs-and-more) for this?

It has an integrated comment / bug management system... and you've already listed your app [there](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/view_app.php?id=32).

Comment: Since when do you hate to plug your own stuff? ;)

Comment: Excellent idea. Plug away, George.

Answer (score 1):

I would just email the developer or post a question in their topic.